# Why I keep getting NA?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a big dataset, and using the package Data.Table in R. One variable is called Visa_status and the other one is Master_status. Both variables can take this values: 1, 3, 4, 5 or NA. I want to combine them in one variable called mv_status following this logic:
If the two variables have NA as values then the value is 9. If one of the variables is a 1, then the value is 1. Any other combination is a 2.
My code is this

```
dataset[ , mv_status08       := ifelse( is.na(Master_status) & is.na(Visa_status), 9, 
                                        ifelse(Master_status == 1 | Visa_status == 1, 1, 2))]
```

My output is this:

```
   Visa_status Master_status mv_status08 N
 1:           1             1           1 164946
 2:          NA            NA           9   6120
 3:           1            NA           1  16590
 4:           1             5           1     58
 5:          NA             1           1    775
 6:           4             4           2    218
 7:           4             3           2      8
 8:           5            NA          NA     85
 9:           5             5           2    364
10:           3             3           2    271
11:           5             1           1     30
12:           3             1           1      8
13:           3             4           2     12
14:           4            NA          NA     81
15:           4             1           1     35
16:          NA             5          NA     14
17:           3            NA          NA    101
18:           1             4           1     15
19:           4             5           2      2
20:          NA             3          NA     72
21:          NA             4          NA     20
22:           1             3           1      1
23:           5             3           2      4
24:           3             5           2      4
25:           5             4           2      2
    Visa_status Master_status mv_status08      N
```

Why I get a NA when there is a NA in one of the variables? Shouldn’t the final step of my code take care of that?

Comment: No. That is because  `Master_status == 1 | Visa_status == 1` has 3 values, a `TRUE, FALSE, NA`. so when `TRUE` it returns 1, when `FALSE` it returns 2 and when `NA` it returns `NA`

Comment: You check if *both* of the columns are `NA`, not *either* column.

Comment: FYI, if you're using `data.table`, use its `fifelse` in place of `base::ifelse`. Alternatively, use `dplyr::if_else`, both are more resilient with non-atomic vectors, and are class-safe, where `base::ifelse` will happily (a) strip class from its values, and (b) makes no attempt to always return the same class if the arguments are ambiguous.

Comment: It would be easier to give you a sure-fire answer if you provide what values you expect in those currently-`NA` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
df[ , mv_status08 := ifelse(is.na(Master_status) & is.na(Visa_status), 9, 
                       ifelse(is.na(Master_status) | is.na(Visa_status), 2, 
                         ifelse(Master_status == 1 | Visa_status == 1, 1, 2)))]
]

 df
    Visa_status Master_status mv_status08      N
 1:           1             1           1 164946
 2:          NA            NA           9   6120
 3:           1            NA           2  16590
 4:           1             5           1     58
 5:          NA             1           2    775
 6:           4             4           2    218
 7:           4             3           2      8
 8:           5            NA           2     85
 9:           5             5           2    364
10:           3             3           2    271
11:           5             1           1     30
12:           3             1           1      8
13:           3             4           2     12
14:           4            NA           2     81
15:           4             1           1     35
16:          NA             5           2     14
17:           3            NA           2    101
18:           1             4           1     15
19:           4             5           2      2
20:          NA             3           2     72
21:          NA             4           2     20
22:           1             3           1      1
23:           5             3           2      4
24:           3             5           2      4
25:           5             4           2      2
    Visa_status Master_status mv_status08      N
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `fcase` :

```
library(data.table)

dataset[ , mv_status08:= fcase(is.na(Master_status) & is.na(Visa_status), 9, 
                               Master_status == 1 | Visa_status == 1, 1, 
                               default = 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
  mutate(my_status08 = case_when(is.na(Master_status) & is.na(Visa_status) ~ 9,
              Master_status == 1| Visa_status == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 2))
```